# solr spatial search with distance to search results

Tags: solr, distance, spatial

I'm able to return all results within a specific radius from geolocation point A, but I want to return the distance of each search result to point A.

I was reading this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

I have this Solr query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/tt/select/?indent=on&facet=true&fq={!geofilt}&pt=51.4416420,5.4697225&sfield=geolocation&d=20&sort=geodist()%20asc&q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&fl=_dist_:geodist(),id,title,lat,lng,geolocation,location&facet.mincount=1
```

And this in my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>   

<field name="geolocation" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

This is one of the results:

```
<doc>
    <str name="geolocation">51.4231086,5.474830699999984</str>
    <str name="id">122</str>
    <str name="lat">51.4231086</str>
    <str name="lng">5.474830699999984</str>
    <str name="title">Eindhoven Museum</str>
</doc>
```

However, with my current query string, I don't see a distance field in the document.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Solr 4?  Adding a function query to "fl" with a label is a Solr 4 thing.  BTW I wouldn't use a leading and trailing underscore as those are reserved for internal Solr use, even if they may work.

Comment: Ah, I'm using 3.5.0, will try to upgrade to 4.2.1. And you mean leading and trailing underscore for the dynamic field, with or withou asterisk? So: <dynamicField name="_coordinate_"?

Comment: For leading and trailing underscores, I am not referring to dynamicField.  I am referring to the \_dist\_:geodist() you added to fl.